# Unwrapping my simple 'Cubes' is distorting (most of) the faces

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I've modeled a 'cube'guy with rounded edges, and I'd like to unwrap him in what feels like the intuitive way-- seams separating head, torso, and legs, and then two seams running the length of the sides... then unwrap along the Z axis while keeping the X and Y 'square'

[image: Cube guy with seams]

But no matter what method I try, I'm getting a lot of distortion on the torso and head

[image: UV Unwrapped]
[image: Distorted faces]

Here are some things I've tried or checked already:

- Vertically, just one seam in the back (or side) instead of one on each side... but that still gives this weird projected/curved distortion
- Conformal Unwrap instead of Angle Based... gives even MORE distortion as it turns the islands into sort of a spiraling shape instead of a symmetrical one
- Cube projection... but that gives me overlapping 'adjacent' faces. For instance, the frontside-righthalf and the rightside-fronthalf are unwrapped on top of each other, so that selecting any 'one' vertex/edge/face of them in the UV editor window actually selects two vertices/edges/faces. I haven't figured out a way to pull them apart without badly stretching other things, as all the islands are somehow connected still
- Smart UV Project... Gives all my big main faces nice, square, non-distorted islands... but makes way too many seams-- it also gives all the tiny faces of the rounded edges their own big separate islands, spread all over. Seems like a nightmare to try and corral all of those to be neighboring (and small) like they should be
- Project From View... Works great! ...for the front, or whichever side I'm viewing when I hit it, but I haven't been able to combine the four (well, five counting top) different angles I need to capture every face
- My Object does not have a scale/transform/rotation... it's at the origin, with scale 1, and no rotation
- There are no n-gons (I know in these pictures the top of the head is one; I have fixed it since, but the unwrap results are the same)

Please forgive me if the solution is just "UV wrapping needs a lot of manual fixing," I am very new to this and it seems like all the tutorials I've followed have much less distortion from the default Unwrap command!

I'm also encouraged/discouraged by the fact that the legs come out exactly as I'd expect, nice and square! But somehow using the same seam-technique on the head and torso DOESN'T!

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: The short answer is that you need more seams/better seam placement. Instead of giving you a full tutorial, I would urge you to read up on the subject rather thoroughly, as having a good understanding early on will help much in the future, and will even change the way you model when you know you need to keep unwrapping under consideration. This guide (although extensive - read: long) has always served me well - https://artisticrender.com/the-definitive-tutorial-to-uv-mapping-in-blender/

Comment: Thank you Christopher, this does look like it'll teach me some useful techniques, and even better, some help in knowing when and how to use them! It's also extremely useful to hear from an expert that I'm not just missing something basic!